# Notepad++ Regular Expressions find&remove

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need some help in Notepad++

Example how it looks at the moment

```
http://www.test.com/doc/rat.rar">rat.rar
http://www.test.com/down/ung.rar">ung.rar
http://www.test.com/read/add.rar">add.rar
```

......

How I want it (just remove after ">....rar)

```
http://www.test.com/doc/rat.rar
http://www.test.com/down/ung.rar
http://www.test.com/read/add.rar
```

Its a list about 1000 lines. So help would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
">[^.]+\.rar
```

Explanation:

```
">        # literal `"` followed by literal `>`
[^.]+     # any character that is not a `.`, repeated at least once 
\.        # literal `.` character
rar       # literal string `rar`
```

---

Note: a couple of other answers pointed out that just `">.*` will work.  This is true, because Notepad++ doesn't appear to support multi-line regular expressions, even with `[\s\S]+`.  Either way will work so it's personal preference.  The regex I gave in this answer  is very verbose and would reduce the likelihood of false positives.  `">.*`, on the other hand, is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

In regexp mode , replace pattern `">.*` with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
">.*
```

Search for this and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your search string should be `">.+\.rar`, and you can just blank out the replace box. This should do the job.

Also, check that you've got regex selected at the bottom of the replace box ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in find `".*` and nothing in replace, that should do what you're looking for.

Remember to check that you've got regex selected at the bottom of the replace box.

Answer (score 0):

Flick the "regular expression" radio button and then use this for your FIND:

```
">[a-z]+\.[a-z]+
```

Then just put empty space for your REPLACE and replace all.

Comment: Thank you! I used this form Andy E

Answer (score 0):

Use -

Find What : `(.*)">(.*)`
Replace With : `\1`

And check `Regular expression` option at the bottom of the dialog.